# SOLR 4.7.1 tomcat 7 setup

Tags: java, tomcat, solr, tomcat7

I am tring to setup a Solr 4.7.1 on Tomcat 7.0.35 here is my folder structure of tomcat

```
/home/mayank/jvm/apche-tomcat-7.0.35/
/home/mayank/jvm/apche-tomcat-7.0.35/bin
/home/mayank/jvm/apche-tomcat-7.0.35/conf
/home/mayank/jvm/apche-tomcat-7.0.35/domains
/home/mayank/jvm/apche-tomcat-7.0.35/domains/solr.mydomain.com
```

solr.mydomain.com is a sub domain for Solr. For setup Solr I do following steps

1. download `Solr 4.7.1.zip` and extract it to `domains/solr.mydomain.com` folder.
2. Copy `solr-4.7.1/dist/solr-4.7.1.war` to `domains/solr.mydomain.com` and rename it to ROOT.war.

What should I do next? how can I set solr home variable? I am accessing with cpanel not command line.

Answer (score 0):

I did not setup solr in tomcat 7, but did setup solr in tomcat 6 several times. Maybe this could help you:

1.) you should add the ports in tomcat setup, where solr should run.
Take a look, if that file exists and change the settings:

```
$tomcat_home/conf/server.xml
```

2.) define the solr application in tomcat. Find out, if there is a file like that:
`$tomcat_home/conf/Catalina/localhost/solr.xml` an add the configuration for solr, like that:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Context docBase="/home/mayank/jvm/apche-tomcat-7.0.35/domains/solr.mydomain.com/solr-4.7.1.war" debug="0" crossContext="true">
  <Environment name="solr/home" type="java.lang.String" value="/home/mayank/jvm/apche-tomcat-7.0.35/domains/solr.mydomain.com/" override="true"/>
</Context>
```

3.) setup tomcat start script, if you run tomcat on linux. The parameter you need depends on the machine, where tomcat is running on. The next example could be an possible set of parameters for the init file:

```
ulimit -v unlimited
export JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib64/jvm/java-1_6_0-ibm-1.6.0/jre/
export JAVA_OPTS="-Xms2048m -Xmx2048m -Dbootstrap_confdir=/home/mayank/jvm/apche-tomcat-7.0.35/domains/solr.mydomain.com/conf/"

export JAVA_OPTS="$JAVA_OPTS  -DhostPort=9080"
export TOMCAT_USER=root
export CATALINA_HOME=/home/mayank/jvm/apche-tomcat-7.0.35
export CATALINA_PID=$CATALINA_HOME/bin/tomcat6.pid
```

The `-DhostPort=9080` depends on your configuration in 1.)